# eclipse cannot export packages from a required project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classpath

I have the following projects setup in Eclipse Indigo SR1:

- Normal Java project (A) which includes package (P)
- Plug-in project (B) which has a copy of the JAR that is exported from A and it then exports package P
- Multiple other Plug-in projects (C...Z) which imports package P

What I want to do is get rid of the manual export and copy of the JAR from project A into project B. I do not want to convert this project to a plug-in project because the same project is used in a legacy application that does not use OSGi.

This is particularly annoying since when I update the JAR eclipse does not pickup the modified class files and all my breakpoints in there go crazy (a separate issue).

I thought I would be able to edit the project properties for B so that A was a "Required project" (Proeprties -> Java Build Path -> Projects), and since that essentially includes the source (at least I guess that is what the entry in .classpath is doing ) I figured I could then export package P from project B. However when I do this, eclipse just complains that plug-in project B does not contain package P.

I figured I could just link the source folders from A into B but that's not really what I want to do.

If a referenced project A is on the classpath then surely the plug-in project A should be able to export those packages, or am I wrong in this assumption?

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Cheers,
Jason.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using maven as your build tool. the tool was built to automate exactly things you've described.  [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we have been using Ant for years now and it's not my decision to make to move to Maven. I've just started using Maven for my own projects so this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your java project into a plugin project (an OSGi bundle) in this case.  You can still use it both as a regular jar and as a plugin.  When you convert it, make sure it creates the MANIFEST.MF.  Just don't create an activator as that would require a dependency on `org.eclipse.osgi`, and don't add any other require-bundle dependencies.

An OSGi bundle is really just a jar (which is fine) with an OSGi MANIFEST.MF that provides information like what packages are exported, any dependencies, etc.